# Changing font family changes font size also

Tags: text, font-face, photoshop, font-size, extendscript

I have a lot of PSD files with some text inside and I need to change their font family to another one. I found a snippet on the internet and adjusted it for my needs - and it does change the font family how I want to but it changes font size also even though I'm not changing it in the code. Am I missing something?

I'm using Photoshop CS6 64bit + Windows 7 64bit.

Code of the script:

```
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    for (var n = 0; n < app.documents.length; n++) {
        app.activeDocument = app.documents[n];
        app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("Change font", "main()");
    }
}

function main () {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theLayers = collectTextLayers(myDocument, []);

    if (theLayers.length > 0) {
        for (var a = 0; a < theLayers.length; a++) {
            theLayers[a].textItem.font = "Lato-Regular";
        }
    }
}

function collectTextLayers (theParent, allLayers) {
    if (!allLayers) {
        var allLayers = new Array;
    }

    for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0;m--) {
        var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];

        if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer") {
            if (theLayer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
                allLayers.push(theLayer);
            }
        } else {
            allLayers = (collectTextLayers(theLayer, allLayers));
        }
    }

    return allLayers;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's changing the font size or does it just look that way?  Different fonts may appear to be somewhat different heights even though they're designed with the same em-size.

Comment: I'm sure, when I'm changing font inside Photoshop the text before and after change is same in size. To be more specific, I'm changing font face Constantine to Lato-Regular.